# How to store Keypair in Android, that should persist even application uninstall?

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, jce, java-security

I want to store Asymmetric keypairs in an Android device, And that should persist even after uninstalling the application. I tried AndroidKeystore, But keys are getting removed, after the app installed. Where as i-os provides the way to store like this.Keychain provides the way to do that. In Android also Keychain is there. Is it able solve my problem?

Comment: Either write to a file in external storage, or write to a file to cloud.

Comment: Android Keychain and credential storage won't help in this case ??